# Using Room for storing system log

Tags: android, android-room

I have a small service in my app which creates a lot of logs. Since these logs are important, I like to persist them locally for later use, even though I show them to use at the same time. I decided to use a small room database in order to store these logs. In this way, my service creates these logs easily and my app shows these logs to users.

My log is really simple. Let's assume my `Entity` and `Dao` is **defined as follows:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "logs_db")
public class LogsData {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private int mId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "level")
    private int mLevel;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "desc")
    private String mDesc;

    public LogsData() {
    }

    @Ignore
    public LogsData(int level, @NonNull String desc) {
        mId = 0;
        mLevel = level;
        mDesc = desc;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        mId = id;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return mLevel;
    }

    public void setLevel(int level) {
        mLevel = level;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return mDesc;
    }

    public void setDesc(@NonNull String desc) {
        mDesc = desc;
    }
}

@Dao
public interface LogsDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void addLog(LogsData logs);

    @Query("DELETE FROM logs_table")
    void deleteAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM logs_table")
    LiveData<List<LogsData>> getAllLogs();
}
```

Ok, now here is my problem. Let assume my table current has 100 rows and I add 1 more log entry by `addLog()`. `getAllLogs()` will return 101 line of logs because it queries the whole table. So, using `getAllLogs()` is the worst possible idea for reading logs from my table. Because for every insert in `logs_db`, I will get the whole content of table **while only new logs are important**.

I'm trying to change `Doa` and/or `Entity` in order to find a way for getting only recent logs added. It means if, for example, 10 lines of the log are in the table and 2 new are added, I just get the newer 2. Any idea how I should do this?

Btw, if you think this idea of using Room DB for my logs is not appropriate, I welcome any new suggestions.

Comment: I don't think that's possible using Room. I would setup a different pipeline for delivering new log entries to my UI along with inserting them in the DB. Using tools such as RxJava publishers.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you want, but how about adding a new column called date, sort descending and use `limit` to prevent seeing all records. If you don't want to display all logs but only newer ones, then create a table called AlreadySeen or something like that and make your first query use `where not in` the AlreadySeen table.

Comment: @ZUNJAE I thought to use a secondary table myself too. But problem is that if I do so, I somehow will need something like transaction for updating AlreadSeen and then getting new log entries. if not,I think I get inconsistencies for my results.

Comment: You might want to consider using a RecyclerView or Pager for this.  This way you can leave the query as is and more data will be presented as the user scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no elegant way for implementing this using Room. However you can set return type Long for the method marked with `@Insert` annotation.

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void addLog(LogsData logs): Long;
```

After that you can use these ids for retriving last added records from DB.

Comment: I thought about this approach too, but the problem is that getting result starting Ids. if I use something like `LiveData<List<LogsData>> getAllLogs(Long startFromId);`, I will need to change `startFromId` after each read from database. But this will be somehow meaningless with `LIveData`. So I'm not sure if this is a proper method.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your need. And the library log4j is exactly what is needed to fulfill this. 
You can print real time log and also store them in log file or database as per your need.

So, you can print log like

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(log4jExample.class.getName());
log.trace("Trace Message!");
log.debug("Debug Message!");
log.info("Info Message!");
log.warn("Warn Message!");
log.error("Error Message!");
log.fatal("Fatal Message!");
```

To save the logs in file or database you need to configure `log4j.properties` file.

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

`LogManager` looks for a file named `log4j.properties` in the **CLASSPATH**. So you need to put this file in your **CLASSPATH**.

Reference:

1. Kindly take a look in official site [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/).
2. Also, here is [some basic tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/index.htm) for this library.
3. log4j.properties [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_configuration.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM LogsData ORDER BY insertDate DESC LIMIT 10")
```

you can use this query to get the last 10 rows but you have to add insert date to order rows using it